# how to show different URL in adress bar by tweaking DNS settings

Tags: redirect, dns

Example:

At the moment I have forwarded www.search.domain.com to www.google.com. I'm trying to achieve that the URL bar will show www.search.domain.com while displaying Googles webpage.  I own domain.com, but I do not own the domain/website Google.com. Is this possible?

I've searched similar threads but couldn't find an answer for my problem yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure. What more do you want to know?

I want my own URL to be shown in the adress bar while aproaching an other website. I've used Google.com in this example to make it a lit bit easier and less confusing. The URL bar shows: www.search.mydomain.com while the website shown is: Google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way back in the dark days of netscape and ie4 it was possible to do this, it was a trivial matter to redirect someone to www.phishedbank.com while showing www.myrealbank.com in the address bar. This was considered a very bad thing. As such for a very long time it has not been possible to modify the address that shows in the address bar, because it is far too easy to exploit for very bad purposes.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I've added an A record which resolves the IP wich statisfied my client.